# How to use database on Vagrant for testing with Codeception

Tags: vagrant, codeception

I use Vagrant and Codception, but when i want to test application localy, I must do it on LAMP (or something like that) server. How can I use database on Vagrant?

Answer (score 3):

All you need is just to setup access to your mysql server that runs on the guest machine (vagrant box) from the host and then to set appropriate database DNS in your codeception.yml config.

Here is some general instructions:

1) Allow your vagrant's mysql server listen all interfaces ssh to your box by setting 'bind-address' option in mysql's my.cnf config and change it's value to 0.0.0.0

2) Grant appropriate privileges to mysql user that will be used to connect to database from the host. 
You can do this running following SQL commands using mysql client

```sql
USE mysql;  
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';  
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where **root** and **mypass** - your database user which will be used from codeception to connect to database and its password and **192.168.0.1** - the ip of the host (read how get host's ip for your gest [here](https://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os))

3) Restart vagrant's mysql server

4) To test connection to vagrant's mysql from the host run

```sh
mysql -h 192.168.33.10 -P 3306  -u root -p
```

(Here **192.168.33.10** - ip of my running vagrant box)

5) Set up DNS in codeception.yml file, e.g.

```rb
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=192.168.33.10;dbname=MyDB'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'mypass'
```

Comment: I have done a similar thing to get Codeception working with my Vagrant install. To clarify: if you want to make this automatic next time you set up your development environment, you should modify your `Vagrantfile` and `bootstrap.sh`.