# PhantomJS + Vagrant + Codeception

Tags: vagrant, phantomjs, codeception

I was wondering is anyone had the chance to have all of this (plus laravel and wordpress) working in the same envirioment(every page is working and I have no problems with laravel or wordpress). 
My question is about is anyone has a configuration working in the right way.

### here is my copy of each

### functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
enabled:
    # add framework module here
    - Laravel5
    - Db
    - Dbh
    - Asserts
    - WebDriver:
        url: 'http://vagrant.test.com/'
        host: '127.0.0.1'
        #host: '192.168.56.102'
        browser: phantomjs
        window_size: 1024x768
        port: 4444
        window_size: 'maximize'
        clear_cookies: 1
        restart: 1
    - \Helper\Acceptance

config:
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=192.168.56.102;dbname=wordpress'
        user: 'wordpress_user'
        password: 'wordpress_password'
        dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
        populate: false
        cleanup: false
        reconnect: true
env:
phantom:
     modules:
        config:
            WebDriver:
                browser: 'phantomjs'

chrome:
     modules:
        config:
            WebDriver:
                browser: 'chrome'
```

---

### acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
    # add framework module here
    - Laravel5
    - Asserts
    - WebDriver:
    - \Helper\Acceptance
config:
        Laravel5:
            cleanup: false
            environment: test
        WebDriver:
            browser: phantomjs
            window_size: 1024x768
            url: 'http://vagrant.test.com/'
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress'
            user: 'wordpress_user'
            password: 'wordpress_password'
            dump: tests/_data/test-dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
env:
phantom:
     modules:
        config:
            WebDriver:
                browser: 'phantomjs'

chrome:
     modules:
        config:
            WebDriver:
                browser: 'chrome'
```

---

### codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
tests: tests
log: tests/_output
data: tests/_data
support: tests/_support
envs: tests/_envs
settings:
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
colors: true
#ramdomise test order
random: true
memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
enabled:
    - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
coverage:
whitelist:
    include:
        - app/*
remote: true
modules:
enabled:
    - Laravel5
    - WebDriver
    - Db
config:
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=vagrant.test.com;dbname=wordpress'
        user: 'wordpress_user'
        password: 'wordpress_password'
        dump: 'tests/_data/myDump.sql'
        populate: true
        cleanup: true
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

## my phantomjs starting code

phantomjs --webdriver=4444

## and this is my error

[Codeception\Exception\ModuleException]
Db: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out while creating PDO connection

Comment: If you run codeception outside vagrant box make sure that mysql allows external connections from host system.  Here explained how to setup access to db inside vagrat box http://stackoverflow.com/a/22734291/1882253

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer. I saw that before asking my question, and yes I tried it but I couldnt make it work :( and that I why I started this thread. Thanks either way for the help :)

Comment: Can you connect to DB from outside vagrant box using mysql client? By the way, why in all three configs you use different DNS? Are all of them pointing to the same DB?

Comment: Yes they all are pointing to the same(127 is just for the local) but yes. 
And yes I have access to the db but codeception doesnt

Comment: I am using that tech stack (codeception -> CentOS -> VM -> vagrant), even have the db on a different VM; all is working as intended. Can you run either / or suite and pass (acceptance / functional)? I noticed the db dsn connection config is different for each.